# How to get the unit of a specific performance counter

Tags: c#, .net, performancecounter, system.diagnostics

I am currently reading different data like CPU Usage via the [`System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter(v=vs.110).aspx) class. After that I'd like to output the values and the unit associated with the counter (ex. MB or GB for memory).

Is there any way to query what unit a value of a performance counter has?

Comment: Memory is measured in `Byte`, so if you want to retrieve `MB` you can do following `counter.NextValue()/1024/1024` . CPU usage is measured in percents.

Comment: Figured that. But I want to dynamically expand the counters I measure and therefor I want to get the units dynamically if possible

Answer (score 1):

Look at the countername property and and look inside the string for (mbytes or kbytes) then if not found look for bytes. this will let you know the scale of the counter (vb.net)

```
if instr(somecounter.countername.tolower , "mbytes")  then
     blah blah
elseif instr(somecounter.countername.tolower , "kbytes") then
     blah blah
elseif instr(somecounter.countername.tolower , "bytes") then
     blah blah
else
     blah blah
end if
```

or

```
dim scale as string = ""
dim xPos as integer = instr(somecounter.countername.tolower, "bytes")
```

> grab an char before and trim it to remove space in front if any
>   otherwise return the scale

```
if xpos>1 then 
   scale=strings.mid(somecounter.countername.tolower, xpos-1, 6).trim
elseif xpos=1 then
```

> the first word of the countername if actually bytes

```
   scale="bytes"
else
   scale="something else"
end if
```